# PL SQL function problems

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I'm trying to write a PL SQL function however I'm having some issues with the formatting and general syntax.

This is my current code:

```
create or replace function getName(name IN varchar, organisation OUT varchar, 
                   xcoord OUT number, ycoord OUT number, errormsg OUT varchar)
return varchar2
as
begin
  Select name, LOCX, LOCY
  from BBT_POI
  WHERE (UPPER(name) LIKE UPPER('%'|| NAME || '%'));
  return NAME;
end;
/

 variable input varchar;
 Variable errormsg varchar;
 Variable organisation varchar;
 Variable x NUMBER;
 Variable y NUMBER;


 execute getName ('yach', organisation, x, y, errormsg);
```

and these are the error messages when I run the create or replace function command:

```
FUNCTION GETNAME compiled
Errors: check compiler log
```

Error(5,3): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

and when I run the execute line I get this:

```
Error starting at line : 40 in command -
execute getName ('yach', organisation, x, y, errormsg)
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 24:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ORGANISATION' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

The procedure should take one IN parameter (name or part of a name), and return four OUT parameters (the name of the organisation, X-coord, Y-coord, error message(or 'none' if no error message is thrown)).

I know currently the code doesn't look for errors however I am just trying to get a simple version working which I can add more functionality to after.

Comment: Does PL/SQL really work with MySQL? Considered tagging Oracle instead?

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  You need an `into` clause, a variable, and to use this variable in the `return` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of problems with your code:
First you are experiencing the `PLS-00428` error which means you are not giving an `INTO` clause.
Example:

```
create or replace function getName(name IN varchar, organisation OUT varchar, 
                   xcoord OUT number, ycoord OUT number, errormsg OUT varchar)
return varchar2
as
begin
  Select name, LOCX, LOCY
  INTO name, XCOORD, YCOORD -- I assume this is how you need them kept
  from BBT_POI
  WHERE (UPPER(name) LIKE UPPER('%'|| NAME || '%'));
  return NAME;
end;
/
```

Next your next block must be defined as an anonymous block. Oracle doesn't know you are trying to use PL/SQL unless you specifically tell it you are.
So your variable stuff needs to be in a block (also you don't need to say variable):

```
DECLARE
 input varchar;
 errormsg varchar;
 organisation varchar;
 x NUMBER;
 y NUMBER;
BEGIN
  getName('yach', organisation, x, y, errormsg);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a tool right now to check whether it works for sure, but try this:

```
create or replace function getName(p_name IN varchar, organisation OUT varchar, 
                   xcoord OUT number, ycoord OUT number, errormsg OUT varchar)
return varchar2
as
begin
  Select name, LOCX, LOCY
  INTO p_name, xcoord, coord 
  from BBT_POI
  WHERE (UPPER(p_name) LIKE UPPER('%'|| p_name || '%'));
  return p_name;
end;
/

 declare
    input varchar;
    errormsg varchar;
    organisation varchar;
    x NUMBER;
    y NUMBER;
 begin
    input:=getName ('yach', organisation, x, y, errormsg);
 end;
```